# Copy data from one table to another - Ignore duplicates Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am using Postgresql db. I have data in two tables. Table A has 10 records and Table B 5 records.

I would like to copy Table A data to Table B but only copy the new entries (5 records) and ignore the duplicates/already existing data

I would like to copy data from Table A to Table B where Table B will have 10 records (5 old records + 5 new records from Table A)

Can you please help me as to how can this be done?

Comment: If you upgrade your outdated Postgres version you can use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming id is your primary key, and table structures are identical(*both table has common columns as number of columns and data type respectively*), use `not exists` :

```
insert into TableB
select * 
  from TableA a 
 where not exists ( select 0 from TableB b where b.id = a.id )
```

Comment: Is the ```Select 0``` intentional or should it be ```select *```

Comment: just style I prefer :) ( whatever you replace instead, including asterisk ) for `not exists`,  while `select 1 ..` for `exists` @gouravkr

Comment: Upvotwd for the response

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to copy rows unique to A that are not in B then you can use INSERT...SELECT. The SELECT statement should use the union operator EXCEPT:

```
INSERT INTO B (column)
SELECT column FROM A
EXCEPT
SELECT column FROM B;
```

EXCEPT (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html) compares the two result sets and will return the distinct rows present in result A but not in B, then supply these values to INSERT. For this to work both the columns and respective datatypes must match in both SELECT queries and your INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Table_A
SELECT *
FROM Table_B
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

Here, the conflict will be taken based on your primary key.